# Passing Values to Enumerated Properties in Shiro ini

Tags: java, ini, shiro

I am using the JDBC Realm and storing authentication data in SQL.  I am storing the salt in the users table and relying on the DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENICATION_QUERY.  To invoke that query I must set the SaltStyle.

Therefore, I need to pass the SaltStyle.COLUMN enumerated value to JdbcRealm through the INI.

SaltStyle is not a class so I cannot create a reference

Whatever I do pass generates this error = org.apache.shiro.config.UnresolveableReferenceException:

Can't find examples from exstensive searching or reference in documentation.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
#====================================================================
# Shiro INI configuration
#
# ===================================================================
[main]
JdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
JdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
sha256Matcher.hashIterations=1
JdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher
JdbcRealm.saltStyle= enum expression needed here
```

Here is the property in JdbcRealm

```
public void setSaltStyle(SaltStyle saltStyle) {
    this.saltStyle = saltStyle;
    if (saltStyle == SaltStyle.COLUMN && authenticationQuery.equals 
             (DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY)) {
        authenticationQuery = DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a ticket to fix this, and its had a patch request which merges cleanly since 2013, but they haven't accepted it because it doesn't work with all collection types. Face. Palm. They'd rather have it not work at all than have it at least work in 80% of cases. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that currently (Shiro 1.2) you cannot configure ENUM values in shiro.ini, see [this](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/shiro-ini-set-enum-value-for-a-property-object-td7578343.html).
However, you can do it in your java code where you invoke realm related methods (like login).  I did it in my servlet init() as follows:

```
public class AuthManager extends HttpServlet {
protected SaltStyle saltStyle = SaltStyle.COLUMN;
// set remaining fields...
   public void init() throws ServletException { 
          Collection<Realm> realms=((RealmSecurityManager) securityManager).getRealms();    
          CustomJdbcRealm jdbcRealm=(CustomJdbcRealm)realms.toArray()[0];
          jdbcRealm.setSaltStyle(saltStyle);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to extend the JdbcRealm and to override the method:

-- CustomShiroJdbcRealm.java:

```
public class CustomShiroJdbcRealm extends JdbcRealm {

    public void setSaltStyle(String saltStyle) {
        super.setSaltStyle(SaltStyle.valueOf(saltStyle));
    }

}
```

--- shiro.ini:

```
jdbcRealm = com.mycompany.CustomShiroJdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.saltStyle = COLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

The request is already fixed. It was possible for me to use

```
[main]
jdbcRealm.saltStyle = COLUMN
```

in my `shiro.ini` config file.